# Preception of a beam from different reference frames

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, speed-of-light, faster-than-light

Lets say there are two spaceships A and B in the vaccum of space. There are a few scenerios that I would like to explore.

Case 1: A and B are both stationary and the distance between them is a light-minute (the distance light travels in a minute). A fires a laser beam at B, now the laser should travels at light speed c, then would B be able to see the laser before it hits?

Case 2: B is moving towards A at 0.1c. When the distance between them is a light minute, A fires a laser. Could B see the laser before it hits?

Case 3: A and B are both moving towards each other at 0.1c. A fires a laser at B when the distance between them is a light minute. Could B see the laser before it hits?

Comment: "Preception"? Or perception?

Answer (score 6):

You can never see a laser coming straight towards you before it hits you. You only see light when it arrives at your eye.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning scenarios 2 and 3, note than in special relativity classical formula for adding speeds, i.e. $v_\text{total} = v_a + v_b$, does not hold. Instead once speeds are relativistic (when one ship moves towards other one or both move towards each other with speed in terms of significant fraction of speed light) this formula holds
$$
v_\text{total} = \frac{v_a+v_b}{1+\frac{v_av_b}{c^2}}.
$$
This means that even in case $v_a=v_b=c$ the resulting speed is still $c$. In other words, you cannot accelerate the laser beam. Whether the ships move towards each other is insignificant.

And of course you cannot see the laser beam before it hits your retina or other sensor, however, I belive that your question was concerning the adding of speeds.